# Tricky Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\mbox{Integrate}\quad
\int_{1}^{2}{\ln\left(x\right) \over x^{2} - 2x + 2}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
This was a question from the $2016$ [Virginia Tech Regional Mathematics Contest](https://www.math.vt.edu/people/plinnell/Vtregional/), which has since passed.)

I tried to decompose the fraction but it didn't factor, I also tried to do something with $\ln\left(x\right)/\left[\left(x - 1\right)^{2} + 1\right]$ and $\arctan$, but I wasn't able to get any of the $\ln$'s to cancel out.

I'd like to learn how to do this problem and am looking for solutions / hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a hidden symmetry.
Through the substitutions $x=z+1$ and $z=\tan\theta$ we have:
$$I=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\log(x)}{(x-1)^2+1}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(z+1)}{z^2+1}\,dx =\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log(1+\tan\theta)\,d\theta$$
and since
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log\left(1+\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta\right)\right)\,d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log\left(\frac{2}{1+\tan\theta}\right)\,d\theta $$
we also have:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\log(2)\,d\theta =\color{red}{\frac{\pi\log 2}{8}}.$$